# Jump to the end of next line in Windows applications

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any universal keyboard shortcut to jump to the end of the next line in Windows applications? For example, similar to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>? However, I just want to move cursor; I don't want to highlight anything.

Comment: Inside text editors or word processors?

Comment: In SQL Server mgt console actually.

Answer (score 3):

If pressing <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> moves the cursor to the end of the next line, you can define a hotkey using [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to simplify the process. For example, if I wanted <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to do the above, I could write this script:

```
!Down::SendInput, {Down}{End}
```

---

Also, you can reuse a hotkey for different applications using the [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) condition. For example, if <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> moves the cursor to the end of the next line in **ApplicationX**, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> does the same in **ApplicationY**, you can define a new, shared hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> like so:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive, ApplicationX
    !Down::SendInput, {Down}{End}
    
#IfWinActive, ApplicationY
    !Down::SendInput, ^+{End}
    
#IfWinActive
```

---

### See Also:

- [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)
- [Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [Key List](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)